# JFileChooser.showOpenDialog() freezing my program

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jfilechooser

I have a problem with the `JFileChooser` class. I am using the following class (that I did write) to load several files one after the other, and it usually works for 2 or 3 files (sometimes 1, sometimes 6, looks random even though it must not be) and at a point, it freezes at `showOpenDialog(null),` no exception is thrown, nothing returned either.
I really don't know where it's coming from.

Here's my class:

```
public class CustomFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    public File chooseFile(String windowTitle, String description, String extension, boolean mustExist) {

        setDialogTitle(windowTitle);
        resetChoosableFileFilters();
        setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
        addChoosableFileFilter(new CustomFileFilter(description, new String[] {extension}));
        setSelectedFile(new File(""));

        if (mustExist) {
            setApproveButtonText("Open");
        } else {
            setApproveButtonText("Save");
        }

        File file = null;
        while (file == null) {

            if (showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                file = getSelectedFile();
                if (mustExist) {
                    if (!file.canRead()) {
                        file = null;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot read from the specified file!", "Error while opening the file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (!file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(extension.toLowerCase())) {
                        file = new File(file.getAbsolutePath().concat(extension));
                    }
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        if (file.canWrite()) {
                            if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you really want to overwrite this file?", "Erasing file", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE) == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                                file = null;
                            }
                        } else {
                            file = null;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot write to the specified file!", "Error while opening the file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        return file;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

EDIT: I tryed running my program on windows and everything works fine. Do you have knowledge of a platforme related problem concerning this class/method ?

Comment: What class is showOpenDialog in?  I'm assuming JFileChooser but I want to be sure

Comment: If you're having this problem on OSX this question might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642158/why-does-jfilechooser-showopendialog-hang-on-mac-osx (Read the comment on the answer)

Comment: @Caleb Yes, showOpenDialog is inherited from JFileChooser class.
I already looked this question before I posted this one, eventhough I'm not sure I really understand was was this guy's problem. But as far as I know, I'm not running any server, or any program on another machine. Let me know if I got something wrong.

Comment: Running in the same issue, having a minimal example working in another project. Cannot get it to work in my current project.

Answer (score 0):

Use your code inside a code block as bellow.

```
private void fileChooserMethod() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           javax.swing.JFileChooser fc_file_selector= new JFileChooser();
           int response =  fc_file_selector.showOpenDialog(null);
           //your code here
        }
    });
}
```