# JFileChooser wont recognize a folder, cannot change directory

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I was running a java program that analyses data, which I wrote.  When I tried to load the data file, the JFileChooser opens as normal, but I cannot double-click the folder to change the working directory.  Anyone else running into this problem, is there a workaround?  I am not sure if it is a java, eclipse, mac, or a combination problem.

I am running eclipse (Oxygen) on a mac 10.12.6 (Sierra) java 1.8.0_121

Here is the main of a SSCE.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
    int status = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
      System.out.println(selectedFile.getParent());
      System.out.println(selectedFile.getName());
    } else if (status == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
      System.out.println("canceled");
    }

}
```

thank you

Comment: Just FYI - have checked your code and it works for me on Windows. Also could you try to play with look and feel like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642158/why-does-jfilechooser-showopendialog-hang-on-mac-osx)

Comment: And one more [here](http://supunmali-myexperience.blogspot.com.by/2012/10/issue-jfilechooser-on-mac-os-x.html)

Comment: What about the permissions of the directory?

Comment: I don't know if that is the cause of your problem, but it might, and it is supremely important anyway: [do not run Swing code from the initial thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [always manipulate your user interface from the event dispatch thread](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/swing_ui.shtml)

Comment: Mikita, It works fine on windows.  I tried the playing with the X11 server, which java should not be touching (most of the time I dont even start an X11 server).  I changed the L&F to the X-platform L&F and it works a little better (sometimes I have to double click multiple times, very annoying).

Comment: Ortomala,  I checked the permissions, no problems there.  Hugues, great point, this is just a small self contained program that exposes the problem.  In my analysis code, I run the JFC in the event dispatch thread.  Anyone else have this problem?  Is it a bug in the Mac L&F?

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing, HowYaDoing?

I have the same problem, my context is slightly different.

I develop a Freeplane add-on "GTD Sync with todo.txt" on a dual boot Windows & Linux machine. Because I wanted to be able to test my add-on on Mac, I installed Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan on Oracle VM VirtualBox according to [this description](https://techsviewer.com/how-to-install-mac-os-x-el-capitan-on-pc-on-virtualbox/).

After installing Freeplane on the Mac VM, I noticed in the open and save dialogues that I could not change to sub directories by double-clicking and that the Open button is greyed out. These are both JFileChooser dialogues. That is very unfortunate, because I specifically wanted to test a JFileChooser dialogue that is part of my add-on. How can I reliably test my add-on, if it is not working for the main app?

I installed another Java app I know: ProjectLibre. The same problem occurs in the Open file dialogue. Freeplane and ProjectLibre are well established apps with a broad user base. I would expect users to complain about this issue, but so far nothing to be found with Google.

I can reproduce that changing L&F to X-platform solves the problem with the greyed-out Open button and that double-clicking a sub directory still does not do anything.

I have tried adding Freeplane to Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility, but that did not solve the problem.

Today I found [a description](https://techsviewer.com/install-macos-high-sierra-virtualbox-windows/) for installing macOS 10.13 on a VM. I tried running Freeplane on this machine and success: JFileChooser dialogues are functioning properly and you can change to a sub directory by double-clicking it! I will use this VM for testing.

So upgrading to macOS 10.13 could solve your problem. I also suspect there must be another solution, otherwise I cannot explain why there are not more complaints about this problem.

EDIT: I tried Freeplane on a macOS 10.12 VM and JFileChooser dialogues are working properly. So it is probably not the version. I have also compared the security settings and file permissions between VMs. I cannot find any difference.

Cheers,

Henk

Comment: The IT staff where I work are planning an upgrade to 10.13.  I'll let you know if it works.  In the meantime, I have switched to javafx.